# How to convert Joda DateTime to UTC MySql timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp, utc

I have a Joda DateTime object representing a UTC time, and wish to store it in a Timestamp field in a MySql table.

I have the following code:

```
String ztime = "2013-10-07T08:00:00Z";  

DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
DateTime dt = parser.parseDateTime(ztime).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into time_test (time) values (?)");
stmt.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp(dt.getMillis()));
stmt.execute();
```

However, when I look in the database, the time that gets store is out by the difference of my database's timezone from UTC.
e.g. when my database is running in UTC+1, and run the above code to save "08:00Z", in the database the Timestamp shows as 09:00.

DateTime's getMillis method says " Gets the milliseconds of the datetime instant from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z."
and MySql's Timestamp says: "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.", 
so I presume it's the MySql conversion that's causing the issue, because the millis it's being initialized with is relative to a fixed UTC time, so it has no need to convert from current time zone to UTC.

My code to read the data back out into a DateTime works fine, and I get the value out that I put in, but I also need this to work with some 3rd-party code over which
I have no control, which expects the Timestamp to be in the correct UTC time.

How do I get the Timestamp field in the database to match my original UTC date/time ?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes that supplant *Joda-Time*.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    Instant.parse( "2013-10-07T08:00:00Z" )  
)
```

Retrieve.

```
myResultSet.getObject( 
    … ,
    Instant.class 
)
```

## java.time

The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, recommending migration to its successor, the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Both are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne. You'll find many of the same concepts in play, so fairly easy to migrate.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Your input string happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2013-10-07T08:00:00Z" ;     // Standard ISO 8601 format.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;  // Parses standard ISO 8601 format by default.
```

The `Instant` class replaces both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange java.time objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

The `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL seems to be akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type. So the code above should work appropriately.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).